# How can write pseudo-code on java to solve this?

Tags: java

Suppose Alice has picked three distinct integers and placed them into a stack S in random order. Write a short, straightline piece of pseudo-code (with no loops or recursion) that uses only one comparison and only one variable x, yet guarantees with probability 2/3 that at the end of this code the variable x will store the largest of Alice's three integers. Argue why your method is correct.

Data Structure on Java

Comment: Why would you use pseudo-code rather than real code?

Comment: What can he do, that's what the assignment says :)

Comment: it's a question and i need to write the solution on pseudo-code

Comment: It's hard to give a hint on this one, to be honest. You go from "nothing" to "the whole answer" in one fell swoop. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you in the middle of the interview at the moment?

Comment: Jon this is a question on Stacks and Queues from this book :
" Data Structures and Algorithms in Java Fourth Edition "

Comment: Maen, can you mark my answer as corrected?

Comment: @thiagoh.. Not before 5 minutes from now.

Comment: If I was OP, I wouldn't accept an incomplete and possibly even incorrect answer. The assignment doesn't mention any function calls.

Comment: @thiagoh yes of curse if your answer is correct :)

Comment: This might be the solution: `x = pop; if (x < peek) x = pop`, but it assumes *peek* is allowed, and somehow it looks too easy to me.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik what is the peek ?

Comment: It's a read operation on the stack, without removing the element from stack.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik if you know this is correct answer , please write it on Answers

Comment: It definitely works, but I don't know if peek is allowed. You should check that in your book first.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik peek is not on my book !

Comment: Well, there you go. If the only operations allowed are push and pop, then this is a non-solution.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik can you write to me the full pseudo-code

Comment: That is the full pseudocode right there.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik " x = pop; if (x < peek) x = pop " ... thats gd
but can explain it : Argue why your method is correct

Comment: I leave the arguing part to you. It's beyond trivial.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik hhhhhhhh thank you man :)

Comment: I'm just reading your book, on page 120 they do mention `peek`.

Answer (score 5):

```
x = S.pop()
return max(S.pop(), x)
```

explanation:

I got a S stack [A, B, C]

```
x = S.pop() // x points to A
return max(S.pop(), x) // compares B to A
```

once I know that the greatest is returned from B and A there is one possibility that the greatest integer is not between those two integers (B and A) that is C
so.. I have two possibilities of getting the greaters number between three -> 2/3

Comment: read the explanation and you'll see that its correct

Comment: this is not for all integer i think !

Comment: @thiagoh.. Now it makes sense. That is why explanation should always be added first. +1 for the answer though.

Comment: This doesn't work. You are not supposed to call any functions and it is non-trivial how you would do it without the call.

Comment: you're right Rohit.. but I forgot and runned to put it thereafter =)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik.. Yeah right. As this is for assignment. thiagoh.. You need to do this without using any function.

Comment: @thiagoh so can you give me the correct pseudo-code for it please

Comment: Rohit.. this is not "a function" is. just a concept widely known.. you're able to use this kind of knowledge when writing pseudo code just like the "return" statement

Comment: @thiagoh You're just cheesing out now. If not, please demonstrate how to write this without the function call.

Comment: Argue why your method is correct.

Comment: @maen The method is so obviously incorrect that it doesn't need any discussion. It point-blank violates the terms of the assignment.

Comment: @Maen I think in my explanation you are able to understand..

Comment: @thiagoh
with no loops or recursion !